# How to match journey builder email sends to Job IDs in Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

How can I go around matching the job ID of a Journey builder send to the list of Job IDs extracted from the data views in automation studio?

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the `_JourneyActivity` data view. You can find fields in the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) located here.

> NOTE JourneyActivityObjectID corresponds to TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID in the _Sent, _Open, _Click, and _Bounce, data views.

Comment: There seem to be multiple instances of the same email in a journey appearing in the report multiple times with a different JourneyActivityObjectID?

Comment: Also TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID is blank in our Sent/open & Click data views?

Comment: not every sent/click/open comes from a triggeredsend. you would need to post your query if your results are not what you expect

Comment: We've managed to get to the bottom of the issue! Thanks!